# how to get page number in SlickGrid while click the page numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slickgrid

I am using slickgrid control with Angularjs. I have some requirement like while click the page number, I need to use that number further in some methods.

HTML CODE

```
 <div id="QueueDetailContainer" class="slick-grid-container">
 <div id="QueueDetailGrid" class="slick-grid defect-release-conatiner" 
 style="height:350px;"></div>
 <div id="QueueDetailPager" class="slick-pager-wrap none"></div>
```

Angular Code

```
  function renderQueueDetailErrorGrid(errorColumns, datadetailError) {
            slickGrid.render('QueueDetailGridError', 'QueueDetailPagerError', ErrorColumns,
                              (datadetailError || []), queueDetailGridPageSize, globalQueueDetailErrorFilter, queueDetailErrorFilter,
                              {
                                  click: function (args) {
                                      if (args.cell == 5) {
                                          ViewErrorDetail(this);
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

```
dataView.onPagingInfoChanged.subscribe(function (e, pagingInfo) {
               var isLastPage = pagingInfo.pageNum == pagingInfo.totalPages - 1;
               var enableAddRow = isLastPage || pagingInfo.pageSize == 0;
               alert(pagingInfo.pageNum);
           });
```